# PHP strip_tag and htmlspecialchars not working for multiple input

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

I'm trying to remove html tags from multiple user input.
I tried it individually it worked, but when i turned it into a function it's **not** removing the html tags...

```
$test = array('name' => '<script>alert("HELLO..");</script>',
                'phone' => '23497999000000'
                );

    (clean($test));
function clean($field)
    {
        foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
            $value = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($value));
        }
        return $field;
    }
```

Comment: You return the original input, not the sanitized value

Comment: `$key => &$value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're set the value of $value, but lose it, when it comes out of scope.
I think it'll be correct:

```
function clean($field)
    {
        foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
            $field[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($value));
        }
        return $field;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, I was hoping maybe something like `$field[$value] = =htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($value));`

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the values to anything, so the value is lost inside your inner loop.

```
function clean($field)
{
    foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
        $field[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($value));
    }

    return $field;
}
```

You also want to keep the cleaned version when returning:

```
$test = clean($test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Option with passing `$value` **by reference**:

```
function clean($field)
{
    foreach ($field as &$value) {
        $value = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($value));
    }
    return $field;
}
```